# enable jquery ui effects in theme .info file

Tags: theming, javascript

Now I should add something like `<?php drupal_add_library('system', 'effects.bounce'); ?>` to my `page.tpl.php` to enable jquery ui effects to use in `views_slideshow_cycle` module.

is there anyway to do this inside theme .info file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to add a Drupal library through a module or theme's .info file. You can add single CSS/JS files, but not a defined library.

That means it's physically possible to download separate copies of system libraries and include them statically in your theme, **but you should not do this**. It's not the 'Drupal' way, and it makes things very difficult to maintain.

You're right in thinking the logic shouldn't be in your page.tpl.php file, it should rather be inside your theme's `hook_preprocess_page` function in the template.php file.

That way the library will be added in time to be included in the page, you maintain a nice level of separation between logic and display, and your theme will be protected in the case that core updates need to be applied to the libraries you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, download jquery ui from http://jqueryui.com/ and put the javascript file you need in your theme then add a line

```
scripts[] = relative/path/to/file.js
```

Just make sure that jquery UI is binding to the jQuery variable and not $ and you should be good to go.

Comment: Drupal core already includes jQuery UI; adding another copy of the library doesn't make sense and will be a nightmare for maintainability

Comment: But that's exactly what the OP seems to be asking for...

Comment: I read it that the OP was looking for a way of including the system javascript libraries by way of an .info file. Making duplicated/forked versions of those files to be manually included is bad for a couple of reasons: 1. It reduces maintainability 2. When other modules in the system include the same libraries the proper way, there will be duplicate JS files in the page. This is bad for page load times and could introduce code conflicts

Comment: Yeah, I understand why you wouldn't want to do it but that doesn't stop me telling the OP how they *could* do what I thought they were asking how to do. You can't use the .info file to pull in system js but you can use it to pull in theme js. If you properly scope and namespace everything you won't get code conflicts. In D6 I regularly ran the painfully outdated core version of jQuery in parallel with a newer version, just need to use noConflict(). No need to downvote me for directly answering a question, downvote the question itself if you think the OP is asking how to do something "bad"..

Comment: I don't think the question is bad though, the OP doesn't ask for a way to get around the fact that libraries can't be added in .info files, he asks if it's possible, which it isn't. Sorry but this just bad advice, hence the down-vote

Comment: yeah, fair call. I guess you could extend the syntax of the .info file similar to the way that Omega does things if you really needed this functionality.

Comment: Yeah that would be a great solution...worthy of a module on drupal.org I think :)